# Disappointed with my own level of performance in group projects and activities

Tags: group-dynamics

I'm attending a CDT (Centre for Doctoral Training) course and am very nearly finished with the first year of my DPhil programme. Part of this has involved doing scientific group projects with other students in my group. We have had all sorts of group projects from the very first day, including group challenges lasting from one day, to a fortnight.

A common feeling I have been getting from these group projects has been one of disappointment and feeling like I haven't made any meaningful scientific contributions to the group other than things like presentational aspects (which are not scientific). Although the goal of the projects is not to produce groundbreaking results, they are meant to be an opportunity to demonstrate how we can come up with novel ways of modelling certain phenomena and representing them mathematically. I consistently feel like I am too slow when it comes to this; by the time I have thought about what could be done to tackle a problem, someone else has already done it, and when I get stuck on a problem (either due to not understanding the maths or simply being rusty as I took some years out of study before embarking upon my DPhil) others manage to take over and suggest other ideas, so I end up feeling lost. No other student or staff has expressed any concerns to me about my group contributions, but this is either because (a) they are conflict-averse and don't want to risk upsetting me, (b) they are aware of my slow contributions but understand my situation of having had a gap between my studies, or (c) there are genuinely no issues to speak of (but I don't feel is the case).

Even though I manage to raise valid points in groups discussions, which others may agree with, I am personally unhappy with my level of contribution to my small group projects and it is most oftem the other group members who make significant strides in actually providing meaningful results. I am not lazy or anything, but it's just that I consider myself to be very slow and rusty (and sometimes incapable) compared to my peers, and near the end I become despirited and lose track of what is going on. I feel like the other group members are much more "switched on" in knowing what to do at a certain stage (e.g. deriving a PDE from a recurrence relation and then applying transform methods) and it could be that because they've come straight from an undergraduate degree that they are more recently well-practiced with their mathematics.

How can I remedy this situation and contribute more in group projects?

Comment: I think it is pretty hard to give any meaningful advice since it probably requires some observation or a very long description of what you actually do now. Keep trying, I suppose, though that isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First up, don't devalue your current contributions. I can only judge you from your post and it's hard to sum up a year of experience in a few paragraphs. Similarly, it's hard to give objective advice when I think your post might be biassed by your own [Imposter Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome), but I feel for you, so I will try.

From your post, here is what I see you **are** contributing:

- Presentation skills. Don't devalue them just because you have them. People agonise over these.
- Feedback for other team members. Peer review is a big part of science and you are the instant reviewer. I am grateful for the team member who has my back and makes sure I'm not talking nonsense.
- You contribute to group discussions. In my experience, it's not difficult to find someone who doesn't.
- Experience from outside of academia. Because a big confirmation [echo chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_chamber_(media)) isn't always desirable.

You also seem to have knowledge of your own skills gap. This is good, because identifying a problem is half way to solving it. If you feel you're rusty on PDEs, find yourself some resources - your old text books if you still have them, or shiny new online courses (that you can skip half of because you remember it!). I don't know about PDEs in particular but some YouTube tutorials for maths have a solid grounding in applications (I really like [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_di4Zn4wz4) for showing not only the maths, but how it is useful). If you see and understand enough applications, you'll eventually start making the leap between problem and possible solution.

Your first goal should be to understand (mostly) everything that your group submits. This helps your knowledge but might also help the team's communications skills. You can't overtake if you can't keep up. But don't sweat the specialist field - you don't have to learn the fine details of something that is ultimately irrelevant to you.

Don't worry about making the leaps of logic faster than your team mates, do worry about ensuring the solutions they (you) propose are valid and well communicated. Be brave and keep asking questions.